# Why is this 5 negative?

Tags: inequality

I'm struggling with the difference between a negative number and a positive number that is being subtracted.

For example, when working on this inequality:
$$
2 - 5x \leq 7
$$

After subtracting 2 from each side, it is:
$$
-5x \leq 5
$$

**Why is the 5 negative?** Wasn't it a positive 5 in the original problem?

If it was negative, shouldn't the original inequality read:
$$
2 - (-5)x \leq 7
$$

**Can someone explain this?**

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Maybe you should read your inequality as $2+(-5x) \leq 7$ because $a-b=a+(-b)$

Comment: Here’s another way to look at it: After you subtract 2 from each side, you have $0-5x\le7$. You can rewrite $0-5x$ as $-5x$. This is actually a pretty interesting question, because when you erase the $0$, the $-$ goes from being a subtraction symbol between $0$ and $5x$ to being part of the number $-5$. It’s ok because $(0-\mbox{anything})$ is the negative of the $\mbox{anything}$. Mathematical notation is handy that way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$2 + (-5x) \leq 7$

Take two from both sides

$(-5x) \leq 5$

You are adding a negative number, which is the same as taking a positive number. This can be thought of as the operator being held by the number on the right. Just as the two is positive, the 5 is negative.

eg:

$0 + (+2) + (-5x)$

Answer (score 0):

$$2-5\times x\leq7,$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$2+(-1)\times5\times x\leq7,$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$2+(-1)\times5\times x-2\leq7-2,$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$(-1)\times5\times x\leq5,$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$(-1)\times x\leq1,$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$(-1)\times (-1) \times x\geq(-1)\times 1,$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$x\geq-1,$$

So the $5$ is not negative. It is just multiplied by $(-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that $a-b=a+(-b).$

Here $2$ is your $a$ and $-5$ is your $-b$.

Using this you will get $2+(-5)$ since $a+(-b).$

Solving this will get you:

$2+(-5x) \leq 7$

Minus $2$ from both sides

$= -5x \leq 5$

Since you are dividing by negative, the sign changes

$x \geq -1$